# By mistake downvote instead of upvote

Tags: discussion, down-votes, etiquette

I was visiting the site via the app and there was a fine answer which deserved, in my opinion, an upvote.

I have just been alerted (because of a drop in my rep points) that instead of *upvoting* I have *downvoted* for error: I touched the wrong part of the screen and didn't notice.

It was an error on my part, the answerer need not be penalized because of this. I cannot remove the downvote because the answer should be edited. What can be done in these cases?

Comment: [Related on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109859/332043)

Comment: @Zoe thanks, but I wasn't sure about this community (maybe there are different habits, specific to Graphic Design...) and I am a very new user in this community (not on SE). Plus, the answer in this case really is fine (content, spelling, grammar...), I should do some very minor edits which I don't like a lot. So I tried to raise the issue on Meta to see what's the view round here.

Comment: That's why I said related and not a duplicate. That's one way, but it's also slightly frowned upon based on the answer with a bounty, but it still happens because it's in some cases necessary (i.e. when there's an accident involved). I'm not sure how much mods can do, but you can at least edit (but it's harder with <2k)

Comment: As long as your edits meet the standard editing requirements and are helpful it's fine to do. Really you're just doing a helpful edit, the change in vote is just and addition.

Comment: @Zoe: We mods can’t do anything about this.